# Minimum Requirements for Auto Increment, Unique, Not Null Primary Key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key, auto-increment, identity

I've seen many examples of CREATE TABLE statements being used to declare primary keys using NOT NULL, UNIQUE, IDENTITY, AUTO_INCREMENT etc., but I'm not sure what the minimum requirements are for setting up a table with an auto-incremental primary key column (of type int).

So I guess that's my question:

What are the minimum requirement for setting up a primary key which auto increments, is unique, and does not allow nulls?

Comment: Unless you're golfing, prefer explicitness over concision, tends to be my rule. Unless you're using a weird edition of SQL Server, you don't incur additional licensing costs by including a few extra words in your SQL.

Comment: I am pretty sure you have not seen an example for SQL Server using `auto_increment`

Answer (score 1):

Primary key is unique by definition. Identity is defaulted to `NOT NULL`. Thus, you can use following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    Id int identity PRIMARY KEY
)
```

If you want some meaningful name, instead of PK__T1__3214EC0744F9FA13 automatically assigned above, you should follow this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE T2
(
    Id int IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Id PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are Assigning a column as primary key,that it self make that column unique and it will not allow NULL values in that column.

Then coming to identity.. Identity will assign auto incremental numbers to the column for every insert to that table. It is not mandatory  that an identity column should be a primary key.

There is no such minimum requirement for setting an identity column as primary key. Usually we will go for an Identity column if there is no other column uniquely identifies the a particular record in a table.Also the sorting and indexing will be more productive if the column is an integer type.

In your case you can simply add a column id with int as data type, set it as identity and assign the primary key to that column.

```
    CREATE TABLE [YourTable]
     (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1)
          CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
      ) ON [PRIMARY]
     GO
```